# Build a jpa specification query without retriving child entity data

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to build a search query to find all Test entity data.
Here are my classes...

TestParent.java

```
@Entity
public class TestParant{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String createdBy;

  @OneToMany(
            targetEntity = Channel.class,
            cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "test_id")
    private List<Channel> channels;
 }
```

Channel.java

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Channel{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Channel channelName;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Test test;

    @OneToMany(
            targetEntity = TvSet.class,
            cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id")
    private List<TvSet> tvSets;

}
```

My specification query...

```
   public Specification<TEST> generateFilterTestQuery(FilterRequest filterRequest) {
        log.info("start to build query  from" + filterRequest);
        return (root, cq, cb) -> {
            Predicate p = cb.conjunction();
            Join<Channel, Campaign> channel = root.join("channels", JoinType.INNER);
            if (!filterRequest.getStartCreatedDate().isEmpty() && !filterRequest.getEndCreatedDate().isEmpty())
                p = cb.and(p,
                        cb.between(root.get(CREATED_DATE),
                                filterRequest.getStartCreatedDate(), filterRequest.getEndCreatedDate()));
            else if (!(filterRequest.getStartCreatedDate().isEmpty()))
                p = cb.and(p,
                        cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(CREATED_DATE),
                                filterRequest.getStartCreatedDate()));
            else if (!(filterRequest.getEndCreatedDate().isEmpty()))
                p = cb.and(p,
                        cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get(CREATED_DATE),

                                filterRequest.getEndCreatedDate()));
            if (!filterRequest.getCreatedBy().isEmpty()) {
                p = cb.and(p,
                        cb.equal(root.get("createdBy"), filterRequest.getCreatedBy()));
            }
          
            if (!filterRequest.getBrandId().isEmpty()) {
                p = cb.and(p,
                        cb.equal(root.get("brandId"), filterRequest.getBrandId()));
            }
            if (!filterRequest.getChannel().isEmpty()) {

                p = cb.and(p,
                        cb.equal(channel.get("channelName"), Channel.valueOf(filterRequest.getChannel())));
            }
            if (filterRequest.getSort().equals(SortEnum.ASC)) {
                cq.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get(CREATED_DATE)));
            } else {
                cq.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get(CREATED_DATE)));
            }
            return p;
        };
    }
```

And my service method...

```
public Page<TEST> filter(FilterRequest filterRequest) throws BaseException {
        try {
            log.info("Getting campaign for filterRequest : {} ", filterRequest);
            // Find Sorted Creatives By filterRequest
            Pageable pageable =
                    PageRequest.of(filterRequest.getPageNumber(), filterRequest.getPageSize());
            return repository.findAll(generateFilterTestQuery(filterRequest),pageable);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new BaseException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The result I'm getting...

```
   "content": [
    {
      "id": 516,
      "name": "Tes",
      "createdBy": "test",
      "brandId": "1",
      "createdDate": 1671529546,
      "channels": [
        {
          "id": 312,
          "channelName": "TV1",
          "channelStatus": "DONE",
          "tvSet": [
            {
              "id": 312,
                "locations": [
                  {
                    "id": 302,
                    "isGeoLocation": true,
                    "cities": [
                      {
                        "id": 282,
                        "distanceUnit": "kilometer",
                      },
                      {
                        "id": 283,
                        "distanceUnit": "kilometer",
                      }
                    ],
       
    }
```

**But I want to get results(channels ) that without getting tvSet array like in below**

```
   "content": [
    {
      "id": 516,
      "name": "Tes",
      "createdBy": "test",
      "brandId": "1",
      "createdDate": 1671529546,
      "channels": [
        {
          "id": 312,
          "channelName": "TV1",
          "channelStatus": "DONE",
          "tvSet": [],
       
    }
```

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue?? Thank you!!

Comment: I'd guess the problem is not "tvSet" being fetched in the first place but rather serialization to JSON. When Jackson (which is likely what you're using due to using Spring) processes a `Channel` entity it will see `tvSets` and thus will access that lazily loaded list. My assumption is that at that point the tv sets will be loaded and serialized. You'd need to tell Jackson not to process that list - either directly ("ignore tvSets") or by adding some custom serializer that is able to identify and ignore non-yet-loaded proxy collections.

Comment: Thank you . your suggested solution is working fine